# Why I get duplicated values during a Parallel Task Execution using an Iterator?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I want retrieve a list of unique customer Ids from a simple XML file (see below), using [Task Parallel Library (TPL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx).

I use [XPathNavigator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator(v=vs.110).aspx) to iterate through xml and retrieve customer Ids. I’m using an iterator with the [Parallel.ForEach(..)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720(v=vs.110).aspx) for task parallelism.

**For some reason I retrieve duplicated customer Ids**. It almost seems like the iterator keeping track of previous reads/iteratoes. I’m expecting new iterator each time when I loop through.

I have tried number of ways still no luck. If someone can point me to the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

(*The attempted full code sample is below.*)

Some simple XML:

```
    private static string Xml()
    {
        return "<persons>" +
               "<person><id>1</id></person>" +
               "<person><id>2</id></person>" +
               "<person><id>3</id></person>" +
               "<person><id>4</id></person>" +
               "<person><id>5</id></person>" +
               "</persons>";
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var navigator = XmlHelper.CreateNavigator(Xml());

        string xpath = "/persons/person";
        var exp = navigator.Compile(xpath);
        var iterator = navigator.Select(exp);

        //Parallel Task scenario returns duplicated customer Ids
        Parallel.ForEach(Iterate(iterator), (a) =>
        {
            string xpathId = "/person/id";
            var value = XmlHelper.SelectString(a.Current, xpathId);
            Console.WriteLine("person id: " + value);
        });
        /*
         * Sample output can be: (notice the duplicated values!)
         * person id: 2
         * person id: 2
         * person id: 4
         * person id: 4
         * person id: 3
         * person id: 1
         * 
         */

        //Sequential scenario displays unique values:       
        //while (iterator.MoveNext())
        //{
        //    string xpathId = "/person/id";
        //    var value = XmlHelper.SelectString(iterator.Current, xpathId);
        //    Console.WriteLine("person id: " + value);
        //}

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static IEnumerable<XPathNodeIterator> 
             Iterate(XPathNodeIterator iterator)
    {
        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return iterator;
        }
    }


public static class XmlHelper
{
    public static string SelectString(XPathNavigator navigator, string xpath)
    {
        return SelectString(navigator, xpath, null);
    }

    public static string SelectString
          (XPathNavigator navigator, string xpath, string defaultVal)
    {
        XPathExpression exp = navigator.Compile(xpath);
        XPathNodeIterator it = navigator.Select(exp);
        it.MoveNext();
        return it.Current.Value;

    }

    public static XPathNavigator CreateNavigator(string input)
    {
        XPathDocument doc;

        using (var reader = new StringReader(input))
        {
            doc = new XPathDocument(reader);
        }

        return doc.CreateNavigator();
    }
}
```

Note I have also the approach take by [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2009/08/12/9867246.aspx) article still no luck.
Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your example is obviously quite small - what problem are you trying to solve here - what sort of size of file are you looking at?

Comment: @Paddy it is a massive xml file that I want to read in parallel. Don't want to do this in sequence. The above is a simplified the that I'm having.

Comment: Obv your actual code will do something else - is the speed bottleneck the XML read or the processing that happens on each node?

Comment: This answer may shed light. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14084660/parallel-foreach-misbehaviour - your ForEach will be ok, it's what you're doing with the results of it that are liklely bad.

Comment: `SelectString` is always retrieving the first value in the iterator. Is that what you actually want?

Comment: You should look at using `Enumerable.AsParallel().ForEach` however, this is unlikely to improve performance as it is likely to be I/O bound.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov no as Nitram mentioned it is the Iterate function causing the issue. I will update his answer (if possible), is not I'll add a new answer.

Comment: @Aron good point. Haven't looked it, although I got it working modifying the iterator return an Enumerable list. I will add the answer sometimes later in the day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Natram and @Paddy!

Both answers pointed me to the right direction. I think @Nitram’s answer was more accurate as he has explained the problem I had it in the first place.

It seems running in parallel, the below code was still causing some duplicates. This is not obvious for smaller collections, but when the number becomes larger it tend to repeat values in multi threaded environments.

```
private static IEnumerable<XPathNavigator> Iterate(XPathNodeIterator iterator)
{
    while (iterator.MoveNext())
    {
        yield return iterator.Current;
    }
}
```

I believe this is why @Paddy mentioned the Iterator is not thread safe.

@Ntram mentioned:

> Parallel.ForEach is easily able to handle Enumerables..

Based on this I went on converting the Iterator to return a list of XPathNaviagator Enumerables

```
private static IEnumerable<XPathNavigator> Iterate(XPathNodeIterator iterator)
        {
            var items = iterator.Cast<XPathNavigator>();
            return items;
        }
```

This solved the problem I had and it worked effectively with the number of items I'm expected to parallelize.

Comment: I am not sure why my solution causes problems, because `Parallel.ForEach` should synchronize the iteration over the enumerable in case it encounters a real IEnumerable. Because the `CastIterator` you are using does internally exactly the same as my implementation.

Comment: @Nitram thanks. Not sure why but I certainly had the issue with your particular implementation. I will try again and see how it is different to yours.

Answer (score 3):

The root of your problem is this function:

```
private static IEnumerable<XPathNodeIterator> Iterate(XPathNodeIterator iterator)
{
    while (iterator.MoveNext())
    {
        yield return iterator;
    }
}
```

If you think about this function you come to the conclusion that there is something very wrong with it.

What this function actually does is: It gives you a Iterator that gives you `n` times the reference to one iterator. Where `n` is the amount of elements in the iterator applied as property.

This messes up everything. `Parallel.ForEach` is easily able to handle Enumerables, but what your function does is applying one iterator multiple times.

I think what you tried to do, is to "convert" your Iterator into a `IEnumerable`. But you need a `IEnumerable` that gives you the values of the iterator and not the iterator over and over again.

So all in all your function should look like this:

```
private static IEnumerable<XPathNavigator> Iterate(XPathNodeIterator iterator)
{
    while (iterator.MoveNext())
    {
        yield return iterator.Current;
    }
}
```

This way your enumerable actually contains the values of your iterator and returns this. With this function you will get all entries in your loop.

Comment: What was I thinking :) Thanks a lot explaining well and pointing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN:

> Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are
>   thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread
>   safe.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator(v=vs.110).aspx

So your iterator is not thread safe for use like this.

Comment: just add updated the question with some missing code. So if the iterator is not thread safe what's the alternative?

Comment: @Spock `Parallel.ForEach` accesses the iterator in a thread safe way.The problem is the `XPathNodeIterator` you are using in the `ForEach` is the same instance across all of the threads due to how you wrote your `Iterate` function. This causes all threads to point at the same node, and that causes your duplicates.

Comment: @Spock - additional code added to question makes this answer a bit redundant - Nitram's answer looks to be a better path to check out.

Comment: @Paddy I think what you said is quite correct. The iterator misbahave/not thread safety during parallel execution. I will add the answer later in the day.